# Issue with calling php script with cron

Tags: php, wordpress, cron

I have set up a cron to call a php script to run some download tasks at a regular interval.
The website is hosted at Bluehost. I have followed the instructions on how to set up a cron and that basically works fine, but the behaviour is different from when calling the script manually which i suspect has to do with directory settings. When using the cron i get errors:

```
Warning: copy(wp-content/uploads/feeds/full/1.csv): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home1/user1/public_html/import/custom-downloader.php on line 86
```

my php code is `copy( $row["externalURL"] , 'wp-content/uploads/feeds/full/'. $localfilename );`

I have also tried below with same result.

`copy( $row["externalURL"] , $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'wp-content/uploads/feeds/full/'. $localfilename );`

I think think that i need to construct the path to `/home1/user1/public_html/import/wp-content/uploads/feeds/full/` but i don't see how to do that.

Comment: When running PHP from cron it may be helpful to use `chdir` to switch to the directory where PHP expects to be running from. If your script runs from a specific directory and works as expected use `chdir` to change to that directory at the top of your script.

Answer (score 0):

First thing's first, make sure that 1.csv exists and that it can be read (there's read permissions on the file)

Second thing, double check if 'wp-content/uploads/feeds/full/1.csv' really is what you want to copy. Your error message indicates that the php script calling the copy method is  /home1/user1/public_html/import/custom-downloader.php. However, the path you specified is *relative*. So your PHP script (barring any changes to the PATH to look for other directories) will look for  /home1/user1/public_html/import/wp-content/uploads/feeds/full/1.csv -- which may not be what you intended!

This can be solved by using an absolute path to your wp-content folder, or by moving this script to the parent directory of wp-content.